# Technique for image library to camera matching app

Tags: android, image-processing

There are many small demonstration projects on Android to analyze video frames and make a determination if the frame has enough similarity to one of a small number of images to trigger an action. In these demonstration projects, these images are often analyzed upon app startup, saved in memory, then checked against video frames. This question seeks to identify a way to go beyond this relatively simple level of starting point for an image matching app.

This question is about how to structure an application that goes beyond that simple demonstration project in that it has or allows for a significant number of images in the library (hundreds), or has the capability to be expanded to manage a significant number of images. The Amazon "Flow" app is an example of how the app would work (but obviously nowhere near the number of match items, and the app may not necessarily require a remote server connection to work).

A high quality answer to this question would identify a way to structure the aforementioned matching app and briefly describe the structure of the app. It would not include technical programming details, but instead would assist a programmer in finding an advisable way to structure such a program. For instance, someone may find an open source app that has an offline component that extracts attributes from images, and that shows or provides a means by which those attributes are made available to the mobile application.

There are many technical question/answer pairs about image matching, but this question is not about the technicalities. It's about identifying a way to structure an app from a more advanced starting point than what the small demonstration projects offer.

Comment: So something like this: https://jalammar.github.io/Supercharging-android-apps-using-tensorflow/ or you may want to directly reference what image processing libraries are under consideration and/or sort of 'structure' are you thinking of.

Comment: The image processing framework I've been looking at is OpenCV.